# windows service to read emails c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I am trying to write a windows service which check my outlook inbox every minute.

I have the following code setup.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timeDelay = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
        timeDelay = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timeDelay.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(WorkProcess);
        timeDelay.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void WorkProcess(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadMyEmail();
    }

  private void ReadMyEmail()
    {
        string content;
        Application outlookApplication = null;
        NameSpace outlookNamespace = null;
        MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
        Items mailItems = null;

        try
        {
            outlookApplication = new Application(); // m getting the error here...
            outlookNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            mailItems = inboxFolder.Items;

            foreach (MailItem item in mailItems)
            {
                if (item.UnRead)
                ......
                ...... all the code for reading emails.

            }
        }
     }
```

I am getting the following error while i am trying to debug the application.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

What am I doing wrong here.. I am just trying to read emails using a service.

Comment: @mason updated..

Comment: @mason updated..

Comment: Well, `Access is Denied` seems pretty clear to me.  Most likely, your service is running as a system user, and not your local user.  It would then not have access.

Answer (score 0):

This should not have been written as a Windows Service. For a "scheduled" application, you could have written this as a normal console application and setup the schedule to run it using Windows Scheduler. You can also set it up to run as you instead of as the system.